# How to extract all command history in one file linux

Tags: bash, shell, input-history

I know how History command works in linux and also that it only displays the commands typed from terminal from that very directory in which the history command was executed,,Isn't it?My intent is to display all the commands typed(History) by me (as a user per se) .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: That is already available in one file i.e. `~/.bash_history` by default

Comment: Everything there is to know about this is in `man history`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the

```
history
```

command, it displays all the history, and is not taking into consideration the 'very directory in which the history command was executed'.

You can output it to a file by using

```
history >> file.txt
```

To see more about the history command, you can visit

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x1712.htm

Comment: well,,i guess no it doesn't help :/ or maybe the command i am looking for is atleast 5 days old ! .. let me do a fresh example to it now and i ll let you know .

Answer (score 4):

`$ history > history_for_print.txt`